# Expand a complex function into a series

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I need to expand this function $\frac{1}{2i+z}$ into a series, z is a complex number. I initially tried substituting $z = x+iy$ into z, combine imaginary terms, then use binomial theorem. However, the solution gives the series in terms of $z$. I am wondering how one would go about this problem to get a series in terms of $z$?

Comment: Factor out $2i$ and see if the form reminds you of anything

Comment: Ahh, what a simple solution, I can't believe I didn't see this. Thanks!

Comment: All good, no problem!

Answer (score 0):

Hint：

Write $\frac{1}{2i+z} = \frac{1}{2i(1+\frac{z}{2i})} = \frac{1}{2i}\times(1 - \frac{z}{2i} + (\frac{z}{2i})^2 - (\frac{z}{2i})^3 + ...)$

As

$$\frac{1}{1-z} = 1+z+z^2+z^3 + ... = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}{z^i}$$